Consistency between UML Class Diagram and Object Diagram regarding multiplicities
Given the following Class Diagram and Object Diagram, is it allowed to create in the OD two Persons for the r2d2 Robot ?
Class Diagram:

Object Diagram:

I am not sure, but I don't think it is possible since there is a 0..1 multiplicity on the person side. So every robot only should have zero or one person.
Moreover, is it allowed to do a composition from an interface to a class, as in the following example?

I think it is fine, because you then have to implement the interface description for your class.

Please post images using the standard stackoverflow method. These can be added inline by users with more reputation.

I've tried to make your title more specific. Don't hesitate to edit it if you think it's not accurate enough

The trick here is that the association in the class diagram is at the level of a qualifier. In this case, the multiplicity on the Person side is for the qualified Robot, i.e. a Robot AND a Token and there can be more than one Token for the Robot.
So it is perfectly possible to have several links from r2d2 to Person instances, under the condition that there is no more than one link per token.
The second part should in principle have been in a different question, because it is only remotely related to the rest. For the sake of efficiency, I'll answer it here: 2. yes, it is exactly as you think (bidirectional navigation should however be shown with open headed arrows and not plain ones) :-)

In UML there is something called a Qualifier. Every value for a Qualifier will produce the multiplicity of instances on the opposite end of the Association. In this case, each value will produce zero or one instance of Person. That means that "jd" would produce no Person, "gl" would produce a Person called "george", and "ts" would produce a Person called "tony".
The black arrows are not valid UML.

Welll spotted. The indians are everywhere... (Maybe a note that they are used in a different context)

Not sure what you mean by Indians or context…

Uhm, the "arrows"

What context did you have in mind? Also, I’m unfamiliar with the “Indians are everywhere” idiom. Could you explain please?

The filled arrow is used in profiles as extends relation. The arrows: indians used arrows a lot (of course not only them) but when I was a kid (some 50 years ago) we used to play cowboy and indian. No longer PC but then it was... When I see PP diagrams with many arrows I just come out with the "too many indians". Probably I'm just too old now.

LOL, I guess my mind is too contextually compartmentalized to think of Indians. The black arrowheads do look like a bit like miniature extension arrowheads, but they register more as as "danger, WIll Robinson" for me, if you're old enough to get that reference.
